# Change input select based on url?

Tags: javascript

I have a Website with a dropdown select menu

```html
<select class="tmcp-field tm-epo-field tmcp-select" 
  name="tmcp_select_0" 
  data-price="" 
  data-rules="" 
  id="tmcp_select_1" 
  tabindex="1"  >
 <option  selected='selected' value="Basislayout_0" data-price="0" data-rules="[&quot;0&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]">Basislayout</option><option  value="Profilayout_1" data-price="24" data-rules="[&quot;24&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]">Profilayout</option> </select>
```

How can I have the Option "Profilayout" preselected on page load, when this line is append to the URL `?start_customizing=yes`

Comment: A little bit more code that is enough to show us what the issue is, would be awesome

Comment: Is pure javascript solution (without external lib like jQuery) preferable?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by this. The condition *location.search.indexOf('start_customizing=yes') != -1* is very raw, so feel free to modify it if needed.

```
if(location.search.indexOf('start_customizing=yes') != -1) {
    document.getElementById('tmcp_select_1').value="Profilayout_1";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7k545dm/1/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How do I exactly use it in my document. I tried this without success. Sorry I am not really good at javascript..

Comment: <code><script type="text/javascript">
var params_exist = location.search.indexOf('start_customizing=yes') != -1

params_exist = true;  // uncomment to check selecting

if(params_exist) {
    document.getElementById('tmcp_select_1').value="Profilayout_1";
}
</script></code>

Comment: @Chris, you should paste this code after your select tag. Preferably right before </body>. So the select tag can be discovered at the moment of JS execution

Comment: Thanks, I placed this right before </body tag but this does not work:

Comment: I used this code: `<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var params_exist = location.search.indexOf('start_customizing=yes') != -1

params_exist = true;  // uncomment to check selecting

if(params_exist) {
    document.getElementById('tmcp_select_1').value="Profilayout_1";
}
});
</script>`

Comment: @Chris is there any error in js dev console? Or maybe you can share to me whole code?

Comment: this is the page [link](http://blitzomat.de/produkt/blitzomat-buchung-profilayout/)

Comment: and with this url it should preselect "profilayout" [link](http://blitzomat.de/produkt/blitzomat-buchung-profilayout/?start_customizing=yes)

Comment: @Chris You actually do not need wrap those code in jquery _ready_ function. http://paste.ofcode.org/3aLusqzwHx7JjyWbQeAbShL . About why it's not working now, it seems to me that something is wrong with jquery at that moment because calling _$_ - return _undefined_

Comment: can I hide you for custom development of a wordpress plugin?

Comment: @Chris Actually i have not worked with wordpress. So sorry, but i have to decline.

Comment: ah ok. I see. Generally It's a fully ajax based plugin where I need to have several function added. nevertheless thanks!

Comment: @Chris there should be the button under the votedown button near the answer rating